# unsupported match type for string: EACH_EQUALS

Tags: karate

Copied from https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1062

I am getting this error message:

```
unsupported match type for string: EACH_EQUALS
```

**For this step:**

```
* match each response/list/cost/Rate == 0.920509
```

**For this xml:**

```
<list>
    <cost>
        <Rate>#present</Rate> // contains 0.920509
    </cost>
    <cost>
        <Rate>#ignore</Rate>
    </cost>
</list>
```

And I have no idea why this isn't working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each` operates only over a list (or array) so use a double-slash:

```
* def response =
"""
<list>
    <cost>
        <Rate>0.920509</Rate>
    </cost>
    <cost>
        <Rate>0.920509</Rate>
    </cost>
</list>
"""
* match //Rate == ['0.920509', '0.920509']

* def temp = //Rate
* match each temp == '0.920509'
```

That should give you enough hints to proceed.

XML can be tricky, so convert it to JSON if you get really stuck: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59730093/143475